# Codewars: Grasshopper - Grade book challenge

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This is one of those times where the solution is staring me right in the face but I can't seem to find it! So please be patient with me. The [kata instruction](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55cbd4ba903825f7970000f5) is the following:

> Complete the function so that it finds the mean of the three scores passed to it and returns the letter value associated with that grade.
>
> ```
> Numerical Score       Letter Grade
>
> 90 <= score <= 100    'A'
> 80 <= score < 90      'B'
> 70 <= score < 80      'C'
> 60 <= score < 70      'D'
> 0 <= score < 60       'F'
> ```
>
> Tested values are all between 0 and 100. There is no need to check for negative values or values greater than 100.

Here is my solution:

```
function getGrade (s1, s2, s3) {
  var score = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 3;
  if (90 <= score && score >= 100) {
      return 'A';
  } else if (80 <= score && score > 90) {
    return 'B';
  } else if (70 <= score && score > 80) {
    return 'C';
  } else if (60 <= score && score > 70) {
    return 'D';
  } else if (0 <= score && score > 60) {
    return 'F';
  }
}

getGrade(5,40,93);
getGrade(30,85,96);
getGrade(92,70,40);
```

Can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In other words, you test for `90 <= score >= 100` instead of `90 <= score <= 100` and so on.

Comment: Moreover, as you're using `else`, you don't need to (and shouldn't) specify both bounds at each level. `if (score > 90) { ... } else if (score > 80) { ... } ...`

Comment: A grade must be within a limit like (score >=90 && score <=100) return 'A'.

Comment: @Teemu I guess you misread it. Its `90` less than score, which is correct. Issue is OP has added `>= 100` and he cannot have values over `100`. Hence failing

Comment: Thank you for the explanations everyone, they really helped me figure out where I was going wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your conditions are wrong and you don't need multiple check in same if .Change your code to this:

```js
function getGrade (s1, s2, s3) {
  var score = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 3;
  if (score >= 90 && score <= 100) {
      return 'A';
  } else if (score >= 80 && score < 90) {
    return 'B';
  } else if (score >= 70 && score < 80) {
    return 'C';
  } else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
    return 'D';
  } else{
    return 'F';
  }
}

console.log(getGrade(5,40,93));
console.log(getGrade(30,85,96));
console.log(getGrade(92,70,40));
```

Comment: The second test in each if() statement is unnecessary, and, to this reader, confusing. YMMV.  For example, the "B" test should be `if (score >= 80) return "B";`

Comment: Even though OP says it's "impossible", I'd add a final `else { throw something } ` clause too.

Answer (score 6):

Your conditions in if statement are all wrong. These are the right conditions

```
function getGrade (s1, s2, s3) {
  var score = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 3;
  if (score >= 90 && score <= 100) {
      return 'A';
  } else if (score >= 80 && score < 90) {
    return 'B';
  } else if (score >= 70&& score < 80) {
    return 'C';
  } else if (score >= 60  && score < 70) {
    return 'D';
  } else {
    return 'F';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use only `if` clauses without `else` parts and check only the lower bound, because you have already checked the upper bound.

The check for upper `100` is missing, because your given range is between `0` and `100`.

```js
function getGrade(s1, s2, s3) {
    var score = (s1 + s2 + s3) / 3;
    if (score >= 90) {
        return 'A';
    }
    if (score >= 80) {
        return 'B';
    }
    if (score >= 70) {
        return 'C';
    }
    if (score >= 60) {
        return 'D';
    }
    return 'F';
}

console.log(getGrade(5, 40, 93));
console.log(getGrade(30, 85, 96));
console.log(getGrade(92, 70, 40));
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself writing long chains of `if`-`else` statements, see if you can find a pattern and use a lookup table. Here, we have only 5 grade buckets, but what if we had 20 or 100? You can see the `if`-`else` approach isn't scalable.

In this case, if we use the string `"FFFFFFDCBAA"` then we've enumerated all 5 grade buckets in a way that lets us index into after dividing the score by 10. The code for that would be: `"FFFFFFDCBAA"[score/10|0]` where `| 0` is the floor operation, chopping off the decimal. The extra `"A"` handles the case of 100.

Secondly, the arguments to the function `(s1, s2, s3)` make no sense. Why 3 scores? If we have 4 score, or 20 scores, the function can't be used and we have to rewrite the whole function with the right number of arguments (and the 20-argument one will be pretty ugly). I realize this header is what the kata author gave you, but there's no reason we can't make it handle any number of arguments using `(...args)` and still pass the tests. If we take the average of the arguments using `args.reduce((a, e) => a + e, 0) / args.length`, we're left with the following solution:

```js
const sum = a => a.reduce((a, e) => a + e, 0);
const avg = a => sum(a) / a.length;
const getGrade = (...args) => "FFFFFFDCBAA"[avg(args)/10|0];

[
  [0],
  [0, 100, 50],
  [90, 95, 100],
  [80, 60],
  [81, 79],
  [80, 59],
].forEach(test => console.log(`${test} => ${getGrade(...test)}`));
```