# How can I loop through function arguments?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, arguments, rest-parameters

```py
def grade(*score):
  for i in range(0, score):
    if score >= 90:
      return "A"
    elif score >=80:
      return "B"
    elif score >=70:
      return "C"
    elif score >=60:
      return "D"
    else:
      return "F"

print(grade(87, 92, 100, 54, 72, 84, 81, 74))
```

I want to be able to loop through the arguments and return the correct grade on each loop.

Comment: This is poor design to begin with. A `grade` function should accept a single argument rather than variable args--the loop should be explicit in the caller. I recommend removing the loop in the function and calling it with `[grade(x) for x in [87...]]`. The reason for this is your data structure externally is explicit, you avoid packing and unpacking things to work with this function and the contract is much clearer. I can't recall the name of this design principle but if I find it I'll share it.

Comment: @ggorlen list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, the typical approach is to say "apply function X to every member of an iterable" rather than "apply function X to an iterable" in cases where each member is being operated on in isolation. It'd be weird if builtins like `int` took an iterable--this operates on a single element, much as `grade` should. `max` or `sum` should take an iterable because they're reduction operations on the entire thing taken as a unit. What's the pattern? Apply the function to the finest granularity commensurate with its purpose.

Comment: Related posts in different languages, same basic problem although in these links I'm whining about `if`-`else` chains instead of looping inside the function... [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930614) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864819) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59201962/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop, append each grade to a list, and return the list.

```
def grade(*score):

  grades = []

  for i in score:
    if i >= 90:
      grades.append("A")
    elif i >=80:
      grades.append("B")
    elif i >=70:
      grades.append("C")
    elif i >=60:
      grades.append("D")
    else:
      grades.append("F")

  return grades

print(grade(87, 92, 100, 54, 72, 84, 81, 74))
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there's a better design available here than looping over args. Apply the function to a single element, which is the minimum unit of granularity you need to evaluate a grade. Baking a loop into every function that you might conceivably want to apply to more than one element is a waste of typing, at best, and really causes readability and maintenance harm for the caller at worst.

As a rule of thumb, when a function operates on one unit, move the loop to the caller (e.g. `int`). Only loop inside a function when it's required to operate on an iterable (e.g. `sort`, `min`, `sum`).

Also, avoid the long `if`-`else` chain. What if you had 30 buckets instead of 5? Writing 30 `if`-`else` statements isn't scalable. Call it premature, but I tend to get uneasy when my `if`-`else` chain grows longer than 3 or so.

Here's my suggestion, which exploits the fact that most of the buckets are divisible by 10, and we need only handle the fact that <60 is a giant bucket and 100 needs an extra bucket. Now we eliminate branches completely.

```
>>> def grade(x): return "FFFFFFDCBAA"[x//10]
... 
>>> grade(99)
'A'
>>> grade(100)
'A'
>>> grade(80)
'B'
>>> grade(89)
'B'
>>> grade(60)
'D'
>>> grade(59)
'F'
```

If you want to be robust, toss in another line and check bounds, raising an `IndexError` if the argument is out of range and possibly a `ValueError` if the argument isn't the right type.

Armed with our new `grade` function, we can apply it to a single grade or an iterable of grades as the caller chooses:

```
>>> grades = [87, 92, 100, 54, 72, 84, 81, 74]
>>> [grade(x) for x in grades]
['B', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C']
>>> list(map(grade, grades)) # alternately
['B', 'A', 'A', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

In a real application, the `grades` list doesn't just come out of thin air as a bunch of literals or variables--it has to be in state as some sort of data structure. If you stick with your function design as-is, you either have an extra loop or you're stuck packing and unpacking data structures, or both.

There's also a semantic/readability issue: `grade(100, 20, 64)` is unclear on sight what operation is supposed to happen. Is `grade` going to return the average of all the scores and produce a final grade? Reduction is the typical pattern for variable argument functions like this (e.g. `sum`, `min`, etc). When the caller uses `[grade(x) for x in grades]`, it's much clearer that we're using a mapping operation, applying the function `grade` individually to each element rather than the collection as a unit. Following this logic, a better function name might be `score_to_letter_grade` or similar which clearly describes the 1:1 operation being performed.

Furthermore, if you just want to grade one thing, you're stuck with a list as the output no matter what which is pretty much an instant deal-breaker for keeping the caller clean. If the builtin `int` worked like this it'd be a really big pain in the rear: `x = int(x)[0]` just to parse `x` from integer to string.

It's not such a horrible situation here because there's such a small amount of code, but big design problems can be explained on micro scales like this, and this misattribution of responsibility can accrue design debt when applied to larger code bases.

Comment: that is an insane amount of effort for such a small problem, really cool approach too!

Comment: Yeah I think I went pretty hard on this one *mops brow*.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this interesting compact way to do it (and im not sure if you were mistaken but yes this works a tuple):

```
def grade(score):
  scores = {range(90,101):"a", range(80,90):"b", range(70,80):"c", range(60,70):"d", range(1,60):"f"}
  return tuple([scores[gradeRange] for i in score for gradeRange in scores.keys() if i in gradeRange])

print(grade((100,30,70)))
```

```
("a","f","c")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for student in grade_tuple:
  print(grade(student))
```

- Assuming you rewrite grade() to just expect one score...